# One way traverse RV from US West to East Coast (or vice versa)

Tags: usa, driving, car-rentals

I was planning to go for a 3-4 weeks trip to the USA with a total of 4 people (two couples) in summer 2019. Someone gave me a hint that it would be possible to traverse new RVs from west coast to east coast (or vice versa), since they are built at one coast and must be moved to the other coast.

I was trying hard to find such an offer, but not could find any. Is there such an offer anywhere?
If not, what would be a good start for searching similar things (i.e. other one-way trips from one coast to another).

If it should matter, we are all from germany, in our early 30s / late 20s and got drivers licenses, credit cards and so on.

Comment: A google search on vehicle relocation returned this January 2018 article by [Thrity Nomads](https://thriftynomads.com/rv-relocation-deals/) on RV Relocation Deals.

Comment: Thank you all - it is indeed a duplicated question. I guess I didn't know the correct keywords to search for, e.g. by "Caravan" i meant "RV", yes. I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are companies that offer this.

http://www.imoova.com/imoova/relocations
https://www.transfercarus.com/

or you can try some of the larger RV rental companies directly.

Typically it's relatively short notice (up to a month or so), so you can't plan much in advance. It's unlikely that you can get a whole cross country trip at the dates you want. So it's a bit of a gamble, and during peak season, it may be difficult to find alternatives on short notice, if this one doesn't play out.